# Clojure - how to automatically initialize once

Tags: clojure

I'm using an agent which refers to a set to keep track of users that i need to notify of an event.  I want it to initialize automatically the first time its called, so this is what I've done so far:

```clj
(declare notify-users!)

(def users-to-notify
  (future
    (def _utn (agent #{}))
    (add-watch _utn :utn notify-users!)
    _utn))

(defn update-user [user-id]
  (send-off @users-to-notify conj user-id))

(defn notify-users! [key reference old-state new-state]
  (println old-state " -> " new-state))
```

This seems to work, but I'm wondering it there are any problems to this approach that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Is it important that it not beinitialized before it is called?

Comment: It's not important; i'd just rather not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am still a learner myself, but I think I may be able to help you express what you are writing in a more idiomatic way.

first of all, get the helper functions defined before you start using them, unless there is a specific reason why you want to declare them first. I tested the code out this way, multiple times and it works fine.

```
(defn notify-users [key reference old-state new-state]
  (println old-state " -> " new-state))

(defonce users-to-notify
  (future
    (let [utn (agent #{})]
    (add-watch utn :utn notify-users)
    utn)))

(defn update-user! [user-id]
  (send-off @users-to-notify conj user-id))
```

Also, perhaps it is a matter of style, but I usually only use def at the top level, so as to avoid confusion about scope for the next programmer reading through my code. `let` is better in this case, and if you test it, you will see that the agent persists within the users-to-notify var. Exclamation points are used to indicate mutating functions, not side-effecting functions, and usually the underscore is used to indicate a value being passed into a function as a param that will not be used in the resulting code. A common example can be found in the use of the `dotimes` function that requires a binding:

```
(dotimes [_ 10] (println "I'm a cheeky monkey!"))
```

I also changed def to defonce, but you should note that defonce is not thread-safe, meaning the expr could get evaluated multiple times.

Comment: The whole point of using the future is so that the initial state is created only once, i.e., the first time it is called.  I don't get any errors when I run my code.

Comment: Could you possibly use a promise?

`(def notify-users! (promise))`
and then later 
`(future (deliver notify-users! (fn [key reference old-state new-state]
  (println old-state " -> " new-state))))`

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check it and see if it helps. Also, my bad on the deref critique. I didn't realize that you were using it in your sendoff to get the agent out of the future. It was throwing up an error on my machine when I first ran it, but when I reloaded my repl, it worked fine like you said.